# How to tell if file or folder could be placed into the Recycle Bin?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, recycle-bin

Say, I have the "`K:\test del USB`" folder. Then I do the following:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sfo = {0};
sfo.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
sfo.pFrom = L"K:\\test del USB\0";
sfo.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO |
     FOF_SILENT | /*FOF_NOCONFIRMATION |*/ FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR |
     FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING;

int res = SHFileOperation(&sfo);
BOOL bFullSuccess = res == 0 && !sfo.fAnyOperationsAborted;
```

So when I run it, the `SHFileOperation` API shows this warning:

> Are you sure you want to permanently delete this folder?

[image]

If the end-user clicks "No", `SHFileOperation` return 0x4c7, which I believe is `ERROR_CANCELLED`.

My question is, if I don't need any UI, how can I know that my file/folder will be permanently deleted (vs. placed into the Recycle Bin)?

Comment: I think if the user decides it, you shouldn't get in his way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That is my own question. I separated it into two for better clarity.

Comment: _'That is my own question.'_ I well know, that's why I marked it.

Comment: WTF. This is not a duplicate!

Comment: You should not repost variations of your earlier asked questions, but ask for more answers or critique existing ones there. If this doesn't help you may consider starting a bounty.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: And you may consider being helpful vs. policing a tech forum.

Comment: OK, flagged for reopening. Let's see ...

Comment: Just in case someone is curious. I was able to resolve this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23770459/843732