# Trying to convert Delphi interface definition to C++ for VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, delphi, com, windows-shell

I need to convert an interface defined in Delpi to C++. I [made small demo project](http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=32661&d=1401422306) that contains all of the stuff shown below.

First is the Delphi function that the person claims to be working on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23721071/843732):

```
function CanFileBeDeletedToRecycleBin(const AFileName: UnicodeString): Boolean;
var
  RecycleBinManager: IRecycleBinManager;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_RecycleBinManager, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IRecycleBinManager, RecycleBinManager));
  try
    Result := RecycleBinManager.WillRecycle(PWideChar(AFileName)) = S_OK;
  finally
    RecycleBinManager := nil;
  end;
end;
```

The rest of the Delphi interface definitions [are here](http://rcrrad.com/2010/10/14/bitbucket-interfaces/).

So I came up with the following C++ code that unfortunately crashes. (Again, let me repeat that the person who wrote Delphi version [claims that it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720519/how-to-safely-delete-folder-into-recycle-bin/23721071?noredirect=1#comment36876767_23721071) fine for him.)

```
HRESULT hr;

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE | COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

// {4A04656D-52AA-49DE-8A09-CB178760E748}
const CLSID CLSID_RecycleBinManager = {0x4A04656D, 0x52AA, 0x49DE, {0x8A, 0x09, 0xCB, 0x17, 0x87, 0x60, 0xE7, 0x48}};

// {5869092D-8AF9-4A6C-AE84-1F03BE2246CC}
const IID IID_IRecycleBinManager = {0x5869092D, 0x8AF9, 0x4A6C, {0xAE, 0x84, 0x1F, 0x03, 0xBE, 0x22, 0x46, 0xCC}};

IRecycleBinManager* pIRBM = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_RecycleBinManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IID_IRecycleBinManager, (void**) &pIRBM);
//  hr = SHCoCreateInstance(NULL, &CLSID_RecycleBinManager, NULL, IID_IRecycleBinManager, (void **)&pIRBM);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //I get a crash on the next line:
    //Unhandled exception at 0x76175ed2: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xa84d252b.
    hr = pIRBM->WillRecycle(L"C:\\test del");

    pIRBM->Release();
}
```

I tried my best to convert that interface from Delphi ([here](http://rcrrad.com/2010/10/14/bitbucket-interfaces/)) to C++. Here's what I got (after @RemyLebeau's suggestions, which unfortunately still didn't work for me.)

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct DELETEDITEM
{
    DWORD dwFileSizeLow;
    DWORD dwFileSizeHigh;
#pragma pack(push,8)
    FILETIME ftDeletionTime;
#pragma pack(pop)
    WCHAR szOriginalPath[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR szDisplacedPath[MAX_PATH];
};
#pragma pack(pop)

enum RECYCLEBIN_TYPE : unsigned char 
{ 
    RBTYPE_VOLUME, 
    RBTYPE_KNOWNFOLDER 
};


#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)

    MIDL_INTERFACE("6E325F88-D12F-49E5-895B-8EC98630C021")
    IEnumRecycleItems : public IUnknown
    {
    public:
        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Next(unsigned celt, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &rgelt, unsigned &pceltFetched) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Next( 
            __RPC__in ULONG celt,
            __RPC__deref_out DELETEDITEM* rgelt,
            __RPC__deref_out ULONG* pceltFetched
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Skip(unsigned celt) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Skip( 
            __RPC__in ULONG celt
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Reset(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Reset(
            void
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Clone(/* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &ppenum) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Clone( 
            __RPC__deref_out IEnumRecycleItems** ppenum
            ) = 0;

    };




    MIDL_INTERFACE("0125E62F-8349-443A-854B-A55FB84CFA35")
    IRecycle : public IUnknown
    {
    public:
        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Compact(void) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFileData( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__deref_out DELETEDITEM* lpData
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetItemCount( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpCount
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetUsedSpace( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpUsedSpace
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsEmpty( 
            void
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeAll( 
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SuspendUpdating( 
            __RPC__in BOOL fSuspend
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RecycleItem( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItem,
            __RPC__in const DWORD dwAttrs,
            __RPC__in const __int64 iFileSize,
            __RPC__deref_out IShellItem** psi
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RestoreItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsRecycled( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__out PBOOL lpRecycled
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumItems( 
            __RPC__in DWORD dwFlags,
            __RPC__deref_out IEnumRecycleItems** enm
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WillRecycle( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath
            ) = 0;

    };




    MIDL_INTERFACE("F964AD97-96F4-48AB-B444-E8588BC7C7B3")
    IRecycleBin : public IUnknown
    {
    public:
        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Compact(void) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFileData( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__deref_out DELETEDITEM* lpData
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetItemCount( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpCount
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetUsedSpace( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpUsedSpace
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsEmpty( 
            void
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeAll( 
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SuspendUpdating( 
            __RPC__in BOOL fSuspend
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RecycleItem( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItem,
            __RPC__in const DWORD dwAttrs,
            __RPC__in const __int64 iFileSize,
            __RPC__deref_out IShellItem** psi
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RestoreItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsRecycled( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__out PBOOL lpRecycled
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumItems( 
            __RPC__in DWORD dwFlags,
            __RPC__deref_out IEnumRecycleItems** enm
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WillRecycle( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(const tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE rbType, const System::WideChar * pszID) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Initialize(
            __RPC__in const RECYCLEBIN_TYPE rbType,
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszID
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeID(/* out */ tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE &rbType, System::WideChar * &pszID) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeID(
            __RPC__deref_out RECYCLEBIN_TYPE* rbType,
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszID
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDList(/* out */ Winapi::Shlobj::PItemIDList &ppidl) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDList(
            __RPC__deref_out LPITEMIDLIST *ppidl
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetLocation(System::WideChar * pszPathBuffer, unsigned cchMax) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLocation( 
            __RPC__in WCHAR* pszPathBuffer,
            __RPC__in UINT cchMax
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetMaxCapacityRange(/* out */ __int64 &lpMin, /* out */ __int64 &lpMax) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetMaxCapacityRange( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpMin,
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpMax
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetMaxCapacity(/* out */ __int64 &lpCapacity) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetMaxCapacity( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpCapacity
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetMaxCapacity(const __int64 lpCapacity) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetMaxCapacity( 
            __RPC__in const __int64 lpCapacity
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetPurgeOnDelete(/* out */ BOOL &fNukeOnDelete) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPurgeOnDelete( 
            __RPC__deref_out BOOL* fNukeOnDelete
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetPurgeOnDelete(const BOOL fNukeOnDelete) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetPurgeOnDelete( 
            __RPC__in const BOOL fNukeOnDelete
            ) = 0;

    };




    MIDL_INTERFACE("5869092D-8AF9-4A6C-AE84-1F03BE2246CC")
    IRecycleBinManager : public IUnknown
    {
    public:

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Compact(void) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFileData( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__deref_out DELETEDITEM* pDeletedItem
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetItemCount( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpCount
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetUsedSpace( 
            __RPC__deref_out __int64* lpUsedSpace
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsEmpty( 
            void
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeAll( 
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE PurgeItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SuspendUpdating( 
            __RPC__in BOOL fSuspend
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RecycleItem( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItem,
            __RPC__in const DWORD dwAttrs,
            __RPC__in const __int64 iFileSize,
            __RPC__deref_out IShellItem** psi
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RestoreItems( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* lpstrItems,
            __RPC__in IFileOperation* pfo
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE IsRecycled( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath,
            __RPC__out PBOOL lpRecycled
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EnumItems( 
            __RPC__in DWORD dwFlags,
            __RPC__deref_out IEnumRecycleItems** enm
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WillRecycle( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszPath
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall DelayCompaction(const BOOL fDelay) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DelayCompaction( 
            __RPC__in const BOOL fDelay
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBinCount(/* out */ int &iCount) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetRecycleBinCount( 
            __RPC__deref_out int* iCount
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBinAt(const int index, const GUID &iid, /* out */ void *ppv) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetRecycleBinAt( 
            __RPC__in const int index,
            const GUID *iid,
            __RPC__deref_out void **ppv
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBin(const System::WideChar * pszPath, const GUID &iid, /* out */ void *ppv) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetRecycleBin( 
            __RPC__in const WCHAR* pszRootPath,
            const GUID *iid,
            __RPC__deref_out void **ppv
            ) = 0;

        //virtual HRESULT __stdcall Refresh(void) = 0 ;
        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Refresh( 
            void
            ) = 0;

    };

#endif
```

Can someone take a look. What am I missing there?

Comment: All this to figure out if a file can be deleted to the recycle bin? Aren't there any Windows OS calls that determine this?   Maybe something in SHLWAPI.DLL?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I would be more than grateful if you can point me to one?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2783/How-to-programmatically-use-the-Recycle-Bin

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That has nothing to do with telling me whether my files will be deleted to the recycle bin or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than translating the interface code from Delphi to C++, you can take the original code from the Russian site, put it in a .pas file as-is, and then add that file to your C++ project.  When you build the project (or just compile the .pas file by itself), a C++ .hpp file will be generated for you, which you can then `#include` into your C++ code.

Doing it this way, the following code works fine for me in C++Builder XE2 on Windows 7:

```
#include "URecycleBinStuff.hpp"
#include <ComObj.hpp>

bool __fastcall CanFileBeDeletedToRecycleBin(const UnicodeString &AFileName)
{
    DelphiInterface<IRecycleBinManager> RecycleBinManager;
    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_RecycleBinManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IRecycleBinManager, (void**)&RecycleBinManager));
    return (RecycleBinManager->WillRecycle(AFileName.c_str()) == S_OK);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (CanFileBeDeletedToRecycleBin(L"C:\\test del"))
        ShowMessage("Can be deleted"); // <-- code makes it here
    else
        ShowMessage("Can not be deleted");
}
```

Here is what the generated .hpp file looks like:

```
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2011 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'URecycleBinStuff.pas' rev: 23.00 (Win32)

#ifndef UrecyclebinstuffHPP
#define UrecyclebinstuffHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member functions
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <SysInit.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <Winapi.Windows.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <Winapi.Messages.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <Winapi.ShlObj.hpp>    // Pascal unit

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Urecyclebinstuff
{
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
#pragma option push -b-
enum tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE : unsigned char { RBTYPE_VOLUME, RBTYPE_KNOWNFOLDER };
#pragma option pop

typedef tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE TRecycleBinType;

struct tagDELETEDITEM;
typedef tagDELETEDITEM *PDeletedItem;

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct DECLSPEC_DRECORD tagDELETEDITEM
{

public:
    unsigned dwFileSizeLow;
    unsigned dwFileSizeHigh;
    #pragma pack(push,8)
    _FILETIME ftDeletionTime;
    #pragma pack(pop)
    System::StaticArray<System::WideChar, 260> szOriginalPath;
    System::StaticArray<System::WideChar, 260> szDisplacedPath;
};
#pragma pack(pop)


typedef tagDELETEDITEM TDeletedItem;

__interface IEnumRecycleItems;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IEnumRecycleItems> _di_IEnumRecycleItems;
__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{6E325F88-D12F-49E5-895B-8EC98630C021}") IEnumRecycleItems  : public System::IInterface 
{

public:
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Next(unsigned celt, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &rgelt, unsigned &pceltFetched) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Skip(unsigned celt) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Reset(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Clone(/* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &ppenum) = 0 ;
};

__interface IRecycle;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IRecycle> _di_IRecycle;
__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{0125E62F-8349-443A-854B-A55FB84CFA35}") IRecycle  : public System::IInterface 
{

public:
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
};

__interface IRecycleBin;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IRecycleBin> _di_IRecycleBin;
__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{F964AD97-96F4-48AB-B444-E8588BC7C7B3}") IRecycleBin  : public System::IInterface 
{

public:
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(const tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE rbType, const System::WideChar * pszID) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeID(/* out */ tagRECYCLEBIN_TYPE &rbType, System::WideChar * &pszID) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDList(/* out */ Winapi::Shlobj::PItemIDList &ppidl) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetLocation(System::WideChar * pszPathBuffer, unsigned cchMax) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetMaxCapacityRange(/* out */ __int64 &lpMin, /* out */ __int64 &lpMax) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetMaxCapacity(/* out */ __int64 &lpCapacity) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetMaxCapacity(const __int64 lpCapacity) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetPurgeOnDelete(/* out */ BOOL &fNukeOnDelete) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetPurgeOnDelete(const BOOL fNukeOnDelete) = 0 ;
};

__interface IRecycleBinManager;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IRecycleBinManager> _di_IRecycleBinManager;
__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{5869092D-8AF9-4A6C-AE84-1F03BE2246CC}") IRecycleBinManager  : public System::IInterface 
{

public:
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Compact(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetFileData(const System::WideChar * pszPath, /* out */ tagDELETEDITEM &lpData) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetItemCount(/* out */ __int64 &lpCount) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetUsedSpace(/* out */ __int64 &lpUsedSpace) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsEmpty(void) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeAll(_di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall PurgeItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SuspendUpdating(BOOL fSuspend) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RecycleItem(const System::WideChar * lpstrItem, const unsigned dwAttrs, const __int64 iFileSize, /* out */ _di_IShellItem &psi) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall RestoreItems(const System::WideChar * lpstrItems, _di_IFileOperation pfo) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall IsRecycled(const System::WideChar * pszPath, PBOOL lpRecycled) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall EnumItems(unsigned dwFlags, /* out */ _di_IEnumRecycleItems &EnumRecycleItems) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall WillRecycle(const System::WideChar * pszPath) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall DelayCompaction(const BOOL fDelay) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBinCount(/* out */ int &iCount) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBinAt(const int index, const GUID &iid, /* out */ void *ppv) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetRecycleBin(const System::WideChar * pszPath, const GUID &iid, /* out */ void *ppv) = 0 ;
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Refresh(void) = 0 ;
};

//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE GUID IID_IEnumRecycleItems;
extern PACKAGE GUID IID_IRecycle;
extern PACKAGE GUID IID_IRecycleBin;
extern PACKAGE GUID IID_IRecycleBinManager;
extern PACKAGE GUID CLSID_RecycleBinManager;

}   /* namespace Urecyclebinstuff */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_URECYCLEBINSTUFF)
using namespace Urecyclebinstuff;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // UrecyclebinstuffHPP
```

If you compare the .hpp file's `IRecycleBinManager` to your manual `IRecycleBinManager`, there are some discrepancies in your code.  Such as, you have the `RecycleItem()` and `IsRecycled()` methods named as `PurgeItems()` and `RestoreItems()` instead, and you have two `RestoreItems()` methods.

Comment: Thanks. Still crashes... I'm using VS2008, so I'm not sure if it can handle the .pas files.

Comment: You never said which C++ compiler you were using, so I assumed C++Builder.  No, .pas files do not work in VC++. But you can take the .hpp I showed you as a starting point to verify your translation.  You have errors in your translation, so fix those first.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention VS part. Darn, I'm still struggling to make it work. What is `_di_IFileOperation` in your code and why is it not a pointer in methods like `IRecycleBinManager::PurgeAll`?

Comment: I updated my original question with the code adjusted for VS from your .hpp file. Still no go, it's still crashing on the same spot. Can you take a look what's wrong with it now?

Comment: Also made a small demo project for VS 2008 with my code: http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=32661&d=1401422306

Comment: `_di_...` types are typedefs for C++Builder's `DelphiInterface<T>` smart wrapper class, which is similar (and different) to ATL's `CComPtr` class. Just a convenient way to automate refcounts and queryinterface.

Comment: Can I ask you one last thing -- is there any way you can post your C++ Builder project that you said worked for you? Somewhere online like, Dropbox, OneDrive. I need to play with it in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me review it and I'll mark this answer.

Comment: I just happened to build your project. Am I missing something or is it just returning "Can be deleted" for every path? I can't make it return anything else.